# How to find out distance between 2 cell of a Grid in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a Grid. I want to calculate the distance between any 2 cells.

Ex:

cell1: (0,1), cell2: (2, 2) ; now the distance is row_distance = 2-0 = 2, col_distance = 2-1 = 1;

I want to find row_distance and col_distance.
I have thought a  solution as given below:

mouse left button down at first cell(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown), then mouse left button up at second cell(PreviewMouseLeftButtonUn).

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True"   PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="grid1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"  PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="grid1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="52*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="39*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="51*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
```

But I could not able to implement function grid1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown grid1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp. I shall be obliged if anyone can help to implement those functions

Please let me know if there is other solution

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.previewmousedown.aspx):

> This is an attached event. WPF implements attached events as routed events. Attached events are fundamentally a XAML language concept for referencing events that can be handled on objects that do not define that event, which WPF expands upon by also enabling the event to traverse a route. Attached events do not have a direct handling syntax in code; **to attach handlers for a routed event in code, you use a designated Add*Handler method**. For details, see [Attached Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

for the row distance

```
int getRowDistance(cell cell1, cell cell2){ //IDK if the cells are objects/structs
    int i,offsetWidth;
    for (i = 0;i < cell1.rowNumber; i++){ //This loop will add the width from 0 to the beginning of the first cell

        cell offCell = cellAtRow(i);
        cellWidth += offCell.width;

    }

    int width = 0;
    for (i = cell1.rowNumber;i < cell2.rowNumber; i++){ //This loop will add the width between the two cells

        cell tempCell = cellAtRow(i);
        width += tempCell.width;

    }
    return width - offsetWidth;
}
```

I hope this makes sense. From what I get off your question, this is what you're looking for. Sorry that this is in plain C, it's the easiest for me to do off the top of my head.